# Dynamically add rows to a bootstrap table that has a form ;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table like this . Now i want this table to add two rows after clicking of a button and still have the form functionality that is that i should be able to able a unique name for the table colums to be able to read this in my controller . All the solutions i have seen  don't maintain the unique name for the added rows . How can i do this ?

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="updateCategory" method=POST>
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
        <tr>
        <th style="width:15%" >Property</th>
        <th style="width:40%">Present Value</th>
        <th style="width:45%">Edited Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
         <td><p class="text-danger" id="id1">Id</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Enter Id"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Cat Key</strong></td>
<!--         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="catKey1" name="catKey1" placeholder="Enter CatKey"></td> -->
       <td><p class="text-danger" id="catKey1">Cat Key</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="catKey" name="catKey" placeholder="Enter CatKey"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
        <td><p class="text-danger" id="name1">Name</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Icon</strong></td>
         <td><p class="text-danger" id="icon1">Icon</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="icon" name="icon" placeholder="Enter Icon"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Icon White</strong></td>
        <td><p class="text-danger" id="iconWhite1">Icon White</p></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="iconWhite" name="iconWhite" placeholder="Enter IconWhite"></td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Color</strong></td>
         <td><p class="text-danger" id="color1">Color</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="color" name="color" placeholder="Enter Color"></td>
  </tr> 
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Post Order Success Message</strong></td>
        <td><p class="text-danger" id="posm1">Post Order Success Message</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="posm" name="posm" placeholder="Enter Post Order Success Message"></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
     <td colspan="3" align="center">
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
 </form>
```

`

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. You want to add 2 rows with a unique id? if so, you can randomize a id...

Comment: @bloC I need to know the name for the columns . As you can see the columns have an input field . So in order to read the values from the input field i should be able to know the name of the columns . It can't be random

Comment: I don't have time for an actual answer but. go to this pen http://codepen.io/warkentien2/pen/Vegexe?editors=0010 
inside JavaScript search the DrawBoard function, that's how you dinamically add elements. Just pass the unique values you want as variables.